# Use different file for testing in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I am using a particular set of URLs for connecting to services. They are there in the config.js file. Now while testing using mocha, I want to use a different set of urls. Is it possible to over-ride the urls configured in the js file from the test cases.This is how my config.js looks -

```
var servercfg = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '9010'
};

var enterprisesercfg = {
  userserurl: 'http://localhost:9020',
  accountserurl: 'http://localhost:9020',
  creditcardserurl: 'http://localhost:9020'
};

var oauth2sercfg = {
  url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/oauth2/verify'
};

module.exports={
  servercfg,
  enterprisesercfg,
  oauth2sercfg
};
```

Comment: urls configured in the js file from the test cases ? does it mean you want separate urls based on environment or something else ?

Comment: ya separate urls for different environments

Comment: There are several libraries available for achieving this like https://www.npmjs.com/package/config . I think the OP has answered with a n example to a library, You can find more info about config.js here https://medium.com/@fedorHK/no-config-b3f1171eecd5

Answer (score 0):

There are already several solutions to manage your configuration; for example this one: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config
You define different files for your different NODE_ENV.

```
//development.json
{
  "someURL": "http://url.com"
}

//test.json
{
  "someURL: "http://url.com"
}
```

So all you need to do to change the file from which you load the config is set the NODE_ENV variable when starting your app.

There are other modules besides this one, it's just an example on how to solve your problem.